# I can't open camera or gallery on APK export Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, export, apk

I am ending an android project. I would like to export an APK to make some friends test it. When Android Studio compile the app on my phone directly everything works fine. But When I try to install the APK and test the app, the camera or gallery won't show up when I press the right button.

Can somebody explain me why please ? ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating project and write code, you are in dev mode and all permissions are allowed to you, you can use camera, internet or what ever, but when you release app you need to add some permissions to `AndroidManifest`,
Find in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and pass permission if you didnt

```
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<manifest>
```